# Orbeon deployment on SAP WAS 7.3

Tags: orbeon

We are trying to deploy orbeon with our web application on SAP WAS. Currently it is running on tomcat with orbeon deployed as a separate WAR file, everything is working. On the SAP WAS we are getting error message "Page not Found" which is produced by not-found.xhtml from config. After turning on logging on orbeon we found the following difference

Tomcat Log: 
2011-07-28 14:40:40,685 DEBUG TeeProcessor  - Freed SAXStore for output id: step-url; approximate size: 392 bytes
2011-07-28 14:40:40,685 DEBUG MSVValidationProcessor  - http://www.orbeon.org/oxf/xml/url validation completed in 3
2011-07-28 14:40:40,692 DEBUG URLGenerator  - Read configuration: [oxf:/ops/xforms/xforms-renderer.xpl|null|null|001|true|false|false|false|[false|true|false|false|false|false]]
2011-07-28 14:40:40,692 DEBUG ProcessorImpl  - Cache [data, class org.orbeon.oxf.processor.validation.MSVValidationProcessor, config, class org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator]: source cacheable for key 'InputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator, inputName: config, CompoundOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.validation.MSVValidationProcessor, outputName: data, key: [CompoundOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator, outputName: data, key: [SimpleOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator, outputName: data, key: [oxf:/org/orbeon/oxf/xml/schemas/url-generator-config.rng|application/xml|null|000|true|false|false|false|[false|true|false|false|false|false]]]]], DocKey [ SimpleOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.DOMGenerator, outputName: data, key: no decorate cfg] ], DocKey [ SimpleOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.DOMGenerator, outputName: data, key: inline input] ]]]]'. STORING object:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$ConfigURIReferences@36fe4e0d
2011-07-28 14:40:40,693 DEBUG URLGenerator  - Config found: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$ConfigURIReferences@36fe4e0d
2011-07-28 14:40:40,693 DEBUG URLGenerator  - OXF Protocol: Using ResourceManager for key **/ops/xforms/xforms-renderer.xpl**

SAP WAS Log:

2011-07-28 12:27:29,372 [] [] DEBUG [org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator] Read configuration: [oxf:/config/not-found.xhtml|null|null|001|true|false|false|false|[false|true|false|false|false|false]]
2011-07-28 12:27:29,373 [] [] DEBUG [org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl] Cache [data, class org.orbeon.oxf.processor.validation.MSVValidationProcessor, config, class org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator]: source cacheable for key 'InputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator, inputName: config, CompoundOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.validation.MSVValidationProcessor, outputName: data, key: [CompoundOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator, outputName: data, key: [SimpleOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator, outputName: data, key: [oxf:/org/orbeon/oxf/xml/schemas/url-generator-config.rng|application/xml|null|000|true|false|false|false|[false|true|false|false|false|false]]]]], DocKey [ SimpleOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.DOMGenerator, outputName: data, key: no decorate cfg] ], DocKey [ SimpleOutputCacheKey [class: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.DOMGenerator, outputName: data, key: inline input] ]]]]'. STORING object:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$ConfigURIReferences@5a5bc44a
2011-07-28 12:27:29,374 [] [] DEBUG [org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator] Config found: org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$ConfigURIReferences@5a5bc44a
2011-07-28 12:27:29,374 [] [] DEBUG [org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator] OXF **Protocol: Using ResourceManager for key /config/not-found.xhtml**
Why would be not-found.xhtml called in SAP WAS? What is the condition for not-found.xtml to be called. More logging is available.

XHTML is generated in our web app from JSP add forwarded for processing to orbeon through the filter, standard separate deployment as suggested in orbeon doc.

Thanks,

Andrei

Comment: Is orbeon supported on SAP WAS?

Answer (score 0):

Orbeon Forms haven't been tested on SAP NetWeaver Application Server recently, and there is no way to tell what the problem is without installing the specific version of SAP NetWeaver Application Server you are using, reproducing the issue, and tracking down the problem. This is too much of a narrow use case to be considered a high priority issue for Orbeon. So, the best way to deal with this is either to:

1. Use an other application server (e.g. Tomcat).
2. Investigate the issue yourself, which you can do, since Orbeon Forms is open source.
3. Get your organization to get Orbeon to do this for you under a [Development Support subscription](http://www.orbeon.com/support-services/development).